# Is it possible to add custom info to manifest file used to distribute iPhone enterprise applications?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an application that will be distributed using the iOS Enterprise Program. I know I'll need to create a manifest file that will be used to download and install the application. What I want is to add some custom info within the manifest file and read this info in the installed application. Does anyone know if this is possible and how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If by 'manifest file' you mean the .plist defining the IPA url etc. then yes, you can add your own custom key/value pairs. It's just a standard plist format which you can edit like any other, and additional key/value pairs will be ignored by the Over The Air distribution mechanism.

If you want to read these values from the application itself, the app will have to download the .plist again itself and parse out the values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You are right, I am talking about this .plist file. If this is the case, my application needs to know the .plist URL. I'll have the same application downloaded from multiple URLs because I have customer specific info and I want that once the application has been downloaded from an URL, it gets the corresponding .plist file to get the customer info. For this, the application needs to know the URL of the .plist file used to download it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well there's no way to get the URL from iOS. I would suggest you build your app with different configurations or targets for each customer, with each target having a different set of data built in to it, or a different URL as a build setting, etc.